# simplify $\frac{1}{4\pi} \left [ y - \frac{e^{-2\pi y }}{2\pi}\right] e ^{\pi y } = \frac{1}{2 \pi}y\sinh(\pi y )$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am having some trouble with the following simplification I came across in my textbook. How does the left hand of the equation simplify to the right hand side? thanks!

$$\frac{1}{4\pi} \left [ y - \frac{e^{-2\pi y }}{2\pi}\right] e ^{\pi y } = \frac{1}{2 \pi}y\sinh(\pi y )$$

this is what I am trying but doesn't seem to work,

$$\frac{1}{4\pi} \left [ y - \frac{e^{-2\pi y }}{2\pi}\right] e ^{\pi y } = \frac{1}{4\pi} \left[ e^{\pi} y - \frac{e^{-\pi y}}{2\pi}\right]$$

Comment: I don't think the $2\pi$ should be there...

Comment: $\frac{1}{4\pi} \left [ y - \frac{e^{-2\pi y }}{2\pi}\right] e ^{\pi y } \neq \frac{1}{2 \pi}y\sinh(\pi y )$

Comment: @Wang could you show me how this is simplified with steps then?

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2 \pi}y\sinh(\pi y )= \frac{1}{2 \pi}y[\frac{e^{\pi y}-e^{-\pi y}}{2}]=\frac{1}{4 \pi}y[1-e^{-2\pi y}]e^{\pi y}$

Answer (score 2):

What is the context? Are there more conditions on $y$?

In general, this is isn't correct

$$ \dfrac{1}{2\pi}y\sinh (\pi y) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi}\left(ye^{\pi y} - ye^{-\pi y}\right) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi}ye^{\pi y}\left(1 - e^{-2\pi y}\right) $$

Comment: its part of a variation of paramaters solution

Comment: I'll need to see the full problem. Please post an update.